# sudden DNS issue with home WIFI affecting a single ubuntu device

Tags: networking, wireless, dns

I've been using my home wifi for months and it worked  fine. Now, all of a sudden I am experiencing issues when connecting with the Ubuntu laptop (all other devices are still able to use the WIFI just fine).

Specifically, for 90% of the web pages that I am trying to access I get the DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN erorr (see picture)  [image]

Finally, if I ping, say, google.com its all good, while their DNS's are unreachable.

```
$ping google.com
PING google.com(sea09s30-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400a:80b::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from sea09s30-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400a:80b::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=112 time=41.0 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 41.010/41.010/41.010/0.000 ms
```

For the DNS I get

```
$ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

What is curious to me is that this started all of a sudden, the only device affected is the laptop and, finally, the issue is corrected if I first connect to the mobile hotspot Wifi and then to the home Wifi network.

What could be causing this? Seems very odd.

Comment: your DNS lookup is using IPv6 but your failed ping to 8.8.8.8 is IPv4. Are you running a server for DNS locally? Might be worth logging into router and see what is happening there - might need a powercycle to start with

Comment: @Crighton What exactly should I be looking at in the router settings?

Comment: Varies between device, but in advanced see if there is a WAN Ipv4 address as well as IPv6. Many allow you to ping from the router - this test your outgoing connection. If this succeeds then there are issues between computer and router not Lan and internet